# Query the partition range on DB2

Tags: sql, db2, database-partitioning, db2-luw

I want to find the starting- and ending point of a DB2 range partition with a query. Is it possible to query these values from any of the system-tables?



*A little more context for my problem:*
We modified some of our huge tables so they're partitioned in daily parts:

```
CREATE TABLE orders(id INT, CRDTTM TIMESTAMP, …)
PARTITION BY RANGE(CRDTTM)
(
    (STARTING ('2014-10-01') ENDING ('2015-15-31') EVERY 1 DAY)
)
```

Is it possible to query the starting- and ending point with normal SQL afterwards? I need to modify a stored procedure that we use so it filters rows that have a timestamp outside of this range (the tables are in a data ware house that's only loaded with data from a short timeframe).

As for the environment: 
We're running a DB2 LUW Version 10.5 on a SUSE Enterprise 11 server. The tables in question are row-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the table `SYSCAT.DATAPARTITIONS`,  specifically the `LOWVALUE`, `HIGHVALUE` and the `LOWINCLUSIVE` and `HIGHINCLUSIVE` columns.

Comment: Thanks, this will work if I get the Max/Min values each table.

Answer (score 2):

This information is in the system catalogs.  The challenge is just finding where and how.  The partition expression itself is in the aptly named `syscat.datapartitionexpression`.

Recreating the particular partition information requires joining together several views.  The example query [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0411melnyk/#dbpart) might help.

You should find the [documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0021355.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-7-23) helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've been looking in the system catalogs but I wasn't able to find the data I need.
`syscat.datapartitionexpression` only holds the column-name while I need the upper and lower limits of the partition range.

Comment: @borst.philipp . . . I would expect the field `DATAPARTITIONEXPRESSION` to actually contain the expression.  You would need to parse it to get the min and max values.